# Add form option for EntityType when its not set (null)

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 6.1 I want to have a custom EntityType form type which allows me to set NULL (empty form field) but has a placeholder in the `<select>`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Admin;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AdminEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'class' => Admin::class,
            'label' => 'Admin :',
            'choice_label' => function (?Admin $admin): string {
                if ($admin instanceof Admin) {
                    return trim(
                        ($admin->getFirstName() ?? "") . " " .
                        ($admin->getLastName() ?? "") .
                        " (" . $admin->getEmail() . ")"
                    );
                }
                return '';
            },
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This form field is used inside filter, so if its NULL, I want to have a select option saying "All". When this option is submitted, it will be treated like empty data. It should also be pre-selected if I fill the form with data and it is NULL for this field.

I have tried everything I can think of but I cannot figure this out. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're supposed to set the `placeholder` option:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder

> It should also be pre-selected if I fill the form with data and it is NULL for this field.

Now this is something that can be achieved via FormEvents, namely the `SUBMIT` form event in your case

Please see the docs on Form events:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: placeholder does not serve the purpose here. It has no effect